# Get data in html from MongoDB using Nodejs/mongoose

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb, ejs

I have two databases, user is working fine and object is not.
I want to pull fields and display in the htmml page.

Here is my get Function

```
const Object= require('./models/Objects');

    app.get('/orders', function(req, res, next) {
      require('connect-ensure-login').ensureLoggedIn(),
      Object.find()
          .then(function(doc) {
            res.render('orders', {Object: req.Order, user: req.user});
            console.log("Order size is " + Object.objectquantity )
          });
    });
```

I want to display in a table below in my orders.ejs

```
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td><%= user.username %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Quantity</td>
        <td> <%=Object.objectquantity %> </td>
    </tr>
```

The user.username is working but not the Object.objectquantity?
Variable is undefined but it matches the variable stored in the schema.

```
const objectSchema= new Schema({
  objectquantity: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Object', objectSchema);
``
```

Comment: Last time I checked "Object" was a reserved Javascript word. Try calling your variable something else? https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp

Comment: I didn't see `username` in your `model` which `username` are you trying to access?